# Remove tree in database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, tree, entity-framework-6

I have a WPF application with EF6 code first with connected scenario and I have problem with removing a tree in my database: It is taking too much time.

Basically, here is my Tree class:

```
    public class Tree
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Tree> Children { get; set; }
        public Tree Parent { get; set; }
        public Tree()
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<Tree>();
        }
    }
```

And here is my function in the **Dal**, with **db** that is the **dbContext** and that has a **dbSet** named **TreeElements**

```
        public async Task<bool> RemoveTreeElementInCascade(Tree tr)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Tree> tmp = tr.Children.ToList();
                db.TreeElements.Remove(tr);
                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (Tree t in tmp)
                {
                    tasks.Add(RemoveTreeElementInCascade(t));
                }
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And when I call this function a Tree that has about 500 elements, it can take about 3 minutes. I don't know what is wrong. I though about Removing only one and do CascadeDelete but I don't know how to do it. Here is the FluentAPI for Tree :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>()
                .HasMany(t => t.Children)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("TreeElementChildren");
                    m.MapLeftKey("TreeElementId");
                    m.MapRightKey("ChildrenId");
                });
```

Maybe I am doing wrong with my removing function, or maybe there is a way to allow cascade delete in this scenario?

Comment: FIrst reconsider the many-to-many association. A tree is special type of graph, a 1:n hierarchy, while a many-to-many self reference is a more generic graph, a network structure. Since you have a tree I think you should turn it into a 1:n association. Next question, which database are you in? Sql Server won't allow cascaded delete and you'll have to use alternatives. General recommendation is to do this at the database level. The relational model doesn't play well with graph structures, but stored procedures/triggers can make it acceptable, whereas an ORM can't avoid the ineptitude.

Comment: @GertArnold Well I think you are right for the many-to-many association, but I have an error when I try a 1:n : System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Entities in 'BddContext.TreeViewElements' participate in the 'TreeViewElement_Children' relationship.
I am using SQL Compact CE 4.0 for the database. And I just saw on another one topic that I had to use triggers for cascade delete but it doens't seems easy.

Comment: I forgot to say it but I also have one reference for the parent in the Tree.